# float to double assignment

Tags: java, floating-accuracy, approximation, double-precision

Consider the following code snippet

```
float num = 281.583f;
int amount = (int) Math.round(num*100f);
float rounded = amount/100.0f;
double dblPrecision = rounded;
double dblPrecision2 = num;
System.out.println("num : " + num + " amount: " + amount + " rounded: " + rounded + " dbl: " + dblPrecision + " dbl2: " + dblPrecision2);
```

The output I get is

```
num : 281.583 amount: 28158 rounded: 281.58 dbl: 281.5799865722656 dbl2: 281.5830078125
```

Why is there the approximation when a float number is assigned to a double variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Approximation actually takes place when you convert decimal fraction to `float`. I might surprise you, but `281.583` can't be represented **exactly** as floating point number in PC. it happens because floating point numbers are represented as sum of binary fractions in PC. `0.5`, `0.25` and `0.125` can be converted precisely, but not `0.583`.

Floats (and doubles) are represented as `Σ( 1/2^i*Bi )`, where `Bi` is i-th bit `(0|1)`. `0.625 =  1/2 + 1/4` for example. The problem is that not all decimal fraction can be converted to *finitie* sum of binary fractions.

Here is how this number is converted (first line is columns definition).

```
i|  *2 and trim|    Bit value|  (2^-1)*bit
    0,583       
1   1,166   1   0,5
2   0,332   0   0
3   0,664   0   0
4   1,328   1   0,0625
5   0,656   0   0
6   1,312   1   0,015625
7   0,624   0   0
8   1,248   1   0,00390625
9   0,496   0   0
10  0,992   0   0
11  1,984   1   0,000488281
12  1,968   1   0,000244141
13  1,936   1   0,00012207
14  1,872   1   6,10352E-05
15  1,744   1   3,05176E-05
16  1,488   1   1,52588E-05
17  0,976   0   0
18  1,952   1   3,8147E-06
19  1,904   1   1,90735E-06
        SUM=    0,582998276
```

Comment: Yes, this is an issue for all doubles and floats.  It doesn't have anything to do with the assignment.

Comment: @Erick Robertson that is what i am trying to explain. the loss of precision just showed up after assignment to double

Answer (score 4):

Because floats are *binary* fractions and thus can only represent your decimal number approximately. The approximation happens when the literal `281.583f` in the source code is parsed into an IEEE 754 float value.

With the floats themselves, this is glossed over because [`println` prints](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29)

> as many, but only as many, more digits
>   as are needed to uniquely distinguish
>   the argument value from adjacent
>   values of type float.

In many cases, that means the decimal value of the literal will be printed. However, when you assign the value to a `double`, the "adjacent values of type double" are usually much, much closer than those of type `float`, so you get to see the true value of you approximated float.

For more details, read [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 0):

The approximation is there the whole time.  It just happens that the double gives enough extra bits that extra stuff shows up.

281.583, for example is in binary (to a lot of digits, but less than double precision):
100011001.1001_0101_0011_1111_0111_1100_1110_1101_1001...

Float allows about 23 bits while double allows about 52 bits. (Can't remember exactly)
100011001.1001_0101_0011_11 which is 281.582946777 in decimal.

As a reference, single precision stores to about 7 decimal digits and double precision to about 16 decimal digits.  That includes all the numbers, so yours is only about 1 digit less than the precision of float.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it your concern is, why this code...

```
float f = 281.583f;
System.out.println(f);
System.out.println((double) f);
```

...prints

```
281.583
281.5830078125
```

(*hey, double provides **more** precision!*)

Here is why...

Feed `438ccaa0` (the hex-format of the bits representing `281.583f`, as given by `Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToRawIntBits(281.583f))`) into the form [here](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/IEEE-754hex32.html). What you'll see is that the float is *actually* represented as `281.58301`. (@Michael Borgwardt answers why it's not printed like that.)

So `281.583` is being printed for `281.58301` when represented as a float. But when you convert `281.58301` to a double, **you can actually get *closer* to `281.58301` than `281.583`**!

Looking at the computations of the above webpage, you can get as close as `281.58300781250000` which is why you see the value `281.5830078125` being printed.

Comment: converting a float to a double does not "get you closer"; you get the same approximation (see my answer).

Comment: @Rick, read carefully. It gets you closer than the value *printed* for the float-representation.

Comment: But you wrote "But when you convert 281.58301 to a double, you can actually get closer to 281.58301 than 281.583". Printing, not conversion, is the key. If you print each with "printf("%.17f")" instead, both give the same answer -- 281.58300781250000000 .

Comment: BTW, I was assuming you meant the float to double conversion in the question -- of 281.583. Were you making a different point, about assigning a different number, 281.58301, directly to a double? If so, that gets you 281.58301000000000158252078108489513397216796875.

Answer (score 0):

In short, don't use float unless you really have to.  You will lose precision and are likely to save very little. Use double and you will save yourself alot of grief.

```
double num = 281.583;
long amount = (long) (num*100);
double rounded = (double) amount/100;
double dblPrecision = rounded;
double dblPrecision2 = num;
```

prints

```
num : 281.583 amount: 28158 rounded: 281.58 dbl: 281.58 dbl2: 281.583
```

Answer (score 0):

The floats and doubles actually have the same value internally; they are just printed differently. Add these lines to your program to view them in hex:

```
System.out.printf("num:           %a\n",num);
System.out.printf("dblPrecision2: %a\n",dblPrecision2);

System.out.printf("rounded:       %a\n",rounded);
System.out.printf("dblPrecision:  %a\n",dblPrecision);
```

This prints

```
num:           0x1.19954p8
dblPrecision2: 0x1.19954p8
rounded:       0x1.19947ap8
dblPrecision:  0x1.19947ap8
```

num = dblPrecision2 and rounded = dblPrecision.

Now 0x1.19954p8 = 100011001.100101010100 = 281.5830078125, and 0x1.19947ap8 = 100011001.1001010001111010 = 281.579986572265625. All that is happening is that they are getting rounded differently upon printing (floats are rounded to a smaller number of digits than doubles).